# How can I project all database columns of a fast changing database?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I often have the situation that the generated jooq code doesn't match the database in production (columns get added all the time).

How can I fetch a weakly typed record, that contains all the database columns?

```
dsl.select(asterisk())
   .from(PERSON)
   .where(PERSON.PERSON_NO.eq(id))
   .fetch()
```

Only returns the columns known at code generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack would be to make sure jOOQ doesn't *know* your tables by using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) in your from clause. That way, jOOQ cannot resolve the asterisk and will try to discover the projection from the actual query results. For example:

```java
dsl.select(asterisk())
   .from("{0}", PERSON)
   .where(PERSON.PERSON_NO.eq(id))
   .fetch();
```

This has been a re-occurring request, I guess we can turn this into a feature: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10182

Note though, that it is usually better to make sure jOOQ *knows* the exact production schema and keep generated code up to date. A future jOOQ will support versioned generated meta data so that the same code can work with different production schema versions more easily:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4232

Answer (score 1):

Just use plain SQL: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual-single-page/#query-vs-resultquery

If that won't work for you, explaining why not might help someone formulate a more suitable answer.